# Halcon - Sort tuple based on list of indices

Tags: sorting, tuples, halcon

I have 2 Tuples, representing a list of point coordinates. I need them sorted by row. Following code sorts the rows tuple, and returns a new tuple containing the the change it made in the ordering of the tuple.. Now I would need to use this information to sort the column tuple the same way.

```
tuple_sort_index (intersection_points_row, Indices)
```

Indices now contains this: `[1, 0, 5, 2, 4, 3]`

so I would need to sort intersection_points_col with these values `[730.5, 1200.15, 515.429, 670.778, 1330.5, 1473.4]` in the same order as displayed in the tuple above..

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tuple := [730.5, 1200.15, 515.429, 670.778, 1330.5, 1473.4]
Indices := [1, 0, 5, 2, 4, 3]

** Sorted
Sorted := Tuple[Indices]

** Inverted
tuple_inverse (Sorted, Inverted)
```

Comment: thank you very much!! didnt imagine that you can pass indices into an array that way.